# Safemath Library version for Solidity v0.5?

Tags: solidity, safemath

Is there a version of the SafeMath library that is compliant to SOlidity v0.5?

Thanks for your inputs in advance

Comment: Yes there is. Search in OpenZeppelin GitHub: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no single "SafeMath" library, but rather a number of different libraries with the same (or similar) names.

Most widely used (though not necessary the best), is [SafeMath library from OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol).

[The most recent released version 0.2.4](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.4.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol#L1) starts with `pragma solidity ^0.5.0;`, so I believe, that it is compatible with Solidity 0.5.x.